# How to I get rid of an anonymous object in an arrayList?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Object> ingred = new ArrayList <Object>();
ingred.add(new Cup()); // From class Cup
ingred.remove(Cup); // Cup cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Can't use either of the remove methods. Please help!!

Comment: You could assign the object to a variable. You could assign the index the object is stored at to a variable. You could iterate through the list and find an instance of `Cup` and then remove it.

Comment: kind of possible in java 8 `ingred.removeIf(Cup.class::isInstance);` (but that removes *all* `Cup` objects)

Comment: @khelwood so the only way would be to store the index for every object?

Comment: @zapl Yeah I came across that as well, but the problem was that I needed to remove them individually.. I ended up using a loop to store the same object multiple times and used remove to get rid of the first instance

Comment: @JMarcusCham Depends what you are trying to do. There is not enough context in your question to be able to tell what your options are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about making it less "anonymous"? Like storing a reference to it:

```
Cup x = new Cup(); 
ingred.add(x); 
ingred.remove(x);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! The problem I had was I didn't want to make a new reference for every single object I stored in the list but it seems storing the same reference object multiple times works and I can remove it using ingred.remove(0), which is the location of the first element.

Comment: Also, is it better to have a list with different object types or separate lists for each type?